# Permutational Question

Tags: permutations, combinations

When I use the equation $P = \frac{n!}{(n - r)!}$ with *n = 3* and *r = 2*, I get 6 permutations. Though, how do I get the amount of permutations without cross-duplicates(e.g A/B and B/A)?

Comment: AB, AC, BA, BC, CA, CB are the six permutations of two distinct letters from {A,B,C}. Could you clarify what you're unsure of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be saying that you want to arrange two objects out of three, such as "ABC". The number of permutations of two of those objects is indeed $6$.

You seem to want to change the problem by considering the arrangements "AB" and "BA" to be the same. In other words, you want two objects out of the three, but this time the order of the two objects does not matter.

In other words, you want the *combinations* of two out of three. This is written in several ways:

$$_3C_2,\quad C(3,2),\quad {3 \choose 2}$$

and the formula is the same for any of those expressions,

$$\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$

and in your particular case, this evaluates to $3$.

To learn more, look up "combinations."

Comment: I misread the question. Your interpretation is very likely correct. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide by 2! (or more generally r!)

And we are now talking about combinations instead of permutations.

The difference between combinations and permutations is that in combinations, the order of the elements are not important.